# What does "SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier" use in Android builds?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html) notes what identifier is used in iOS/Windows builds, but not Android builds.  What identifier does `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` use on Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why that is not mentioned in the Doc.

Last time I checked, Unity uses  [`Secure.ANDROID_ID`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/3785314) to get the Android ID string then converts that to string. If you do that, you should the the-same value as [`SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html). This is what's happening on my device.

Unfortunately, more things are going on in the background.

Unity documented their Unique Identifier Details implementation on their [forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unique-identifier-details.353256/).

**1**. Get DeviceId with `context.getSystemService(Context.TElEPHONY_SERVICE).getDeviceId()`

**2**.If **#1** fails, get Android ID with `context.getContentResolver().getString(Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

**3**.If **#2** fails, get the Mac Address.

**4**.Convert result from **#1**, **#2** or **#3**(which ever one that was successful) to MD5 Hash.

It's worth reading that [forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unique-identifier-details.353256/) post since the behavior is a little different on some Unity versions.

Here is a sample code provide by them on what it looks like:

```
// Hash an input string and return the hash as
// a 32 character hexadecimal string.
static string getMd5Hash(string input)
{
    if (input == "")
        return "";
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}

static string generateDeviceUniqueIdentifier(bool oldBehavior)
{
    string id = "";
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaClass contextClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Context");
    string TELEPHONY_SERVICE = contextClass.GetStatic<string>("TELEPHONY_SERVICE");
    AndroidJavaObject telephonyService = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    bool noPermission = false;
    try
    {
        id = telephonyService.Call<string>("getDeviceId");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        noPermission = true;
    }
    if(id == null)
        id = "";
    // <= 4.5 : If there was a permission problem, we would not read Android ID
    // >= 4.6 : If we had permission, we would not read Android ID, even if null or "" was returned
    if((noPermission && !oldBehavior) || (!noPermission && id == "" && oldBehavior))
    {
        AndroidJavaClass settingsSecure = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.Settings$Secure");
        string ANDROID_ID = settingsSecure.GetStatic<string>("ANDROID_ID");
        AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver");
        id = settingsSecure.CallStatic<string>("getString", contentResolver, ANDROID_ID);
        if(id == null)
            id = "";
    }
    if(id == "")
    {
        string mac = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/sys/class/net/wlan0/address");
            mac = reader.ReadLine();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        id = mac.Replace(":", "");
    }
    return getMd5Hash(id);
}
```